# Bokeh - Do not show tooltip if it has missing value

Tags: python, tooltip, bokeh

I'm working on a bokeh figure that shows cluster activity. When a user hovers over a particular processor, I want it to show statistics about the processor. Heres the code:

```
TOOLTIPS = [
    ("Usage", "@{usage}%"),
    ("Name", "@name"),
    ("PID", "@pid"),
    ("Command", "@command"),
    ("User", "@user"),
]

p = figure(title="Cluster Activity",
           plot_width=1200,
           plot_height=700,
           x_range=nodes,
           y_range=list(reversed(cores)),
           tools='hover',
           toolbar_location=None,
           tooltips=TOOLTIPS
           )
```

This works, but I don't want to show tooltips with a value of None. For example, if a particular processor, has a None value for User, the tooltip should not contain a user value, rather than showing "User : ???".

Is there any way to do this? I can't seem to find anything similar to this in the tutorials. I'd like to avoid writing custom JS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also create the tooltips dynamically using JS callback attached to the `HoverTool` (Bokeh 1.1.0)

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool, CustomJS, FactorRange

pid = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
user = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3', 'user4', None, 'user6']
name = ['name', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6']

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(pid = pid, user = user, name = name))

p = figure(x_range = FactorRange(*name), sizing_mode = 'stretch_both', title = "Test", toolbar_location = None, tools = "")
p.vbar(x = 'name', top = 'pid', width = 0.2, source = source)

code = '''  hover.tooltips = [["Name", "@name"], ["PID", "@pid"]];
            if (cb_data.index.indices.length > 0) { 
                index = cb_data.index.indices[0];
                counts = source.data.user[index]

                if (counts != null)
                    hover.tooltips = [["Name", "@name"], ["User", "@user"], ["PID", "@pid"]];                                       
            } '''
hover = HoverTool()
hover.callback = CustomJS(args = dict(source = source, hover = hover), code = code)
p.add_tools(hover)

show(p)
```

Due to the comment below I checked the code for Bokeh v2.1.1 and it seems it still works after modifying the callback to:

```
code = '''  if (cb_data.index.indices.length > 0) { 
                const index = cb_data.index.indices[0];
                const counts = source.data.user[index]

                if (counts != null) {
                    hover.tooltips = [["Name", "@name"], ["User", "@user"], ["PID", "@pid"]];  
                }
                else {
                    hover.tooltips = [["Name", "@name"], ["PID", "@pid"]];
                }                                     
            } '''
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This does not work anymore. `const` has to be added in front of every defined variable. But even so, when the tooltips are updated, they are not showing anymore when hovering over the corresponding bar

Comment: That is why I always add Bokeh version in my answers.

Comment: Haha indeed, but it seems that you were the only one in the whole internet that has answered this question. So I have linked this question with a bug in github, hopefully someone will answer soon: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/11260

Comment: Thanks for the changes. Can you describe why by pushing the `hover.tooltips = [["Name", "@name"], ["PID", "@pid"]];` inside the if fixes things? Does it have to do with Javascript changes?

Comment: Bokeh is full of surprises when it comes to backwards compatibility. I only see that in the original version the tooltip was rendered twice while in the new version it's being rendered just once. If the first rendering takes too long it may kind of disturb the second one and we won't see it.

Answer (score 3):

I see two ways of doing this:

**1. Checking if Name is None with Python and using multiple HoverTool**

Since HoverTool is a bokeh.models.tools you can add it via

```
p.add_tools(hovertool)
```

So you could make two instances of HoverTool and split your data to two data sources:

```
p = figure(title="Cluster Activity",
           plot_width=1200,
           plot_height=700,
           toolbar_location=None)

without = p.square(name="without", ##your filtered data source without names)
with = p.square(name="with", ##your filtered data source with names)

hoverwith = HoverTool(names=["with"],tooltips=TOOLTIPS = [
        ("Usage", "@{usage}%"),
        ("Name", "@name"),
        ("PID", "@pid"),
        ("Command", "@command"),
        ("User", "@user"),
    ])

hoverwithout = HoverTool(names=["without"],tooltips=TOOLTIPS = [
    ("Usage", "@{usage}%"),
    ("PID", "@pid"),
    ("Command", "@command"),
    ("User", "@user"),
])


p.add_tools(hoverwith, hoverwithout)
```

With the names attribute of HoverTool you can specify for which glyps the hover is rendered. I haven't tested the code.

**2. Using custom JS (just mentioning for the sake of completeness)**

In case you have many different combinations of possible missing values, I only see JS as a way to do this, have a look here: https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/4VxEbPaLqnA/-qYLDsbZAwAJ