# Mysterious bokeh hovertool behavior (multiple boxes)

Tags: python, datetime, bokeh

I have some data that's missing values in some places. For some reason, only hovering on the data AFTER the last break in the data shows just one box on hover, as expected. The data between the last break and second to last shows 3 boxes. (The screenshot didn't capture the mouse for some reason. In the left picture it's to the left of the hole in the curve, in the right picture - to the right.) Hovering on data between second and third to last breaks in data generates 5 boxes. And so on ... The values in the extra boxes don't change with cursor movement and are all different too, and the boxes are shifted and display only in the last chunk of data.
Any thought on what's going on here?

I tried making a minimal example, but then the problem disappeared... Maybe someone can spot what's wrong with the original code?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import warnings
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file, output_notebook
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral11, colorblind, Inferno, BuGn, brewer
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, value, LabelSet, Legend, ColumnDataSource, LinearColorMapper, BasicTicker, PrintfTickFormatter, ColorBar
from bokeh.models.widgets import DateRangeSlider, CheckboxButtonGroup
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from json import loads
import ast

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


minD = data['Date'].values[0]
maxD = data['Date'].values[-1]


def datetime(x):
    return np.array(x, dtype=np.datetime64)


TOOLS = 'save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom'
p = figure(y_axis_type="linear",
           plot_height=400, tools=TOOLS, plot_width=1300,
           x_range=(minD, maxD), x_axis_type="datetime")

source = ColumnDataSource(data={
        'Date': datetime(data['Date']),
        'x': data['x'],
        'y': data['y'],
        'z': data['z']})

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Position (m)'


def add_plot(y, color):
    new_plot = p.line(x='Date', y=y, line_width=1, color=color, source=source)
    return new_plot


x = add_plot('x', 'red')
y = add_plot('y', 'green')
z = add_plot('z', 'blue')

checkbox = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=['x', 'y', 'z'], active=[0, 1, 2])
checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(x=x, y=y, z=z), code="""
    //console.log(cb_obj.active);
    x.visible = false;
    y.visible = false;
    z.visible = false;
    for (i in cb_obj.active) {
        //console.log(cb_obj.active[i]);
        if (cb_obj.active[i] == 0) {
            x.visible = true;
        } else if (cb_obj.active[i] == 1) {
            y.visible = true;
        } else if (cb_obj.active[i] == 2) {
            z.visible = true;
        }
    }
""")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p), code="""
    var a = cb_obj.value;
    p.x_range.start = a[0];
    p.x_range.end = a[1];
""")

start_date = pd.to_datetime(minD)
end_date = pd.to_datetime(maxD)
range_slider = DateRangeSlider(start=start_date, end=end_date,
                               value=(start_date, end_date), step=1)
range_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)


def get_hovertools():
    hovers = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z}
    for k, v in hovers.items():
        hovers[k] = HoverTool(mode='vline', renderers=[v])
        hovers[k].tooltips = [('Date', '@Date{%F %H:%M:%S.%u}'),
                              (k, '@{'+k+'}{%0.2f}m')]
        hovers[k].formatters = {'Date': 'datetime', k: 'printf'}
        p.add_tools(hovers[k])


get_hovertools()

layout = column(p, widgetbox(checkbox), widgetbox(range_slider))

show(layout)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mode = 'vline'` in the `HoverTool` so if the line is very steep there can be many points having similar y-coordinate in the glyph so the hover will hit them all and display multiple boxes. Setting the mode to `mode = "mouse"` should help

Comment: Thanks, Tony! I did fix the weird behavior, but now the boxes for all three plots (i have x, y, z overlaid ) come up as on top of each other, so I can't see all of them. Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out some of my dates were `NaT` ... really strange that that's how it decided to handle them, by only displaying proper hover boxes on the values after the last `NaT` ... bokeh baffles me .....

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679754/bokeh-do-not-show-tooltip-if-it-has-missing-value/55686184#55686184) about how to avoid displaying missing values.